# responsive css circle loader

Tags: css, loader, clip-path

I'm trying to make a css circle loader and I'm about 90 percent of the way there.

Currently I have it so that the data attribute data-progress on the .loader class controls the progress.  Everything works, but when the progress is animating it becomes unmasked for the animation, and then masked again as soon as the animation ends.  I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Here is a link to the JS bin for a look at what I have so far, I'd love to hear any thoughts or solutions to this.  Thanks in advance for any help!

http://jsbin.com/sofiho/edit?html,css,js,output

Sorry for not adding a code snippet!  Here it is:

HTML:

```
<div class="loader" data-progress="60">
    <div class="loader-progress"></div>
    <div class="loader-progress"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
    $mask-right-side : polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 50% 0%, 50% 100%);
    $mask-left-side  : polygon(50% 100%, 50% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);

    .loader {
        position      : relative;
        width         : 200px;
        height        : 200px;
        background    : lightgray;
        border-radius : 50%;

        .loader-progress {
            position : absolute;
            top      : 0px;
            left     : 0px;
            width    : 100%;
            height   : 100%;
            &:before,&:after {
                transition : transform cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,.97) 0.32s;
            }
            &:before,
            &:first-child:after {
                content       : "";
                position      : absolute;
                top           : 0px;
                left          : 0px;
                width         : 100%;
                height        : 100%;   
                border-radius : 50%;
            }
            &:first-child {
                z-index : 1;
                -webkit-clip-path: $mask-left-side;
                &:before,&:after {
                    background : green;
                    -webkit-clip-path: $mask-right-side;
                }
            }
            &:last-child {
                -webkit-clip-path: $mask-right-side;
                &:before {
                    transform  : rotate(180deg);
                    background : green;
                    -webkit-clip-path: $mask-right-side;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $i         : 0;
    $increment : 180deg / 100;

    @while $i < 101 {
        .loader {
            &[data-progress="#{$i}"] {
                .loader-progress {
                    &:first-child {
                        &:after {
                            transform : rotate($increment * $i);
                        }
                    }
                    &:first-child:before {
                        transform : rotate($increment * $i * 2);
                    }
                    @if $i > 50 {
                        &:last-child:before {
                            transform : rotate($increment * $i * 2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $i : $i + 1;
    }
```

Comment: even if you link to demo, best is to have the code within a snippet here (icone is [<>] )(will be reachable anytime to anybody and can easily be clicked copied into answers ... make it easy for helpers ;)

Comment: noted!  Updated the question.